# Trying to pass from TableView to UIWebview causes crashes

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, storyboard

As you can read in the title, I am having a slight problem. I am using the MWParser for an RSS feed. I edited the code for when you click on an RSS title, it opens in an in-app browser. 
This is the code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (_webViewController == nil) {
        self.webViewController = [[[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] autorelease];
    }

    MWFeedItem *entry = [parsedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _webViewController.entry = entry;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];


    // Deselect
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

However, I get this crash message:

```
2013-02-11 18:21:15.644 GlennKessler[24209:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Hugo/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/7F35D6C0-BFBE-4CD9-A1CE-7DC54CD6B249/GlennKessler.app> (loaded)' with name 'WebViewController''
```

From what I can tell, this is happening because I am using Storyboards, not NIBs. How do I have it open the view in the storyboard that is running off of the code in WebViewController? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the [NSBundle mainBundle] by nil since the nib is in the default bundle, and make sure that the nib file (WebViewController.nib) is in the Bundle you are packaging the app

Comment: But I am using a Storyboard. Not a NIB. Not sure how that would fix it.

Comment: Well, you are loading the ViewController using a Nib file, that is why, it's trying to find the file inside the bundle.